# Email delay up to 48 hours between server and clients

Tags: email, delay, spf

Our LMS system is hosted on AWS China. For some reason, ever since the beginning, all of our outbound email from the LMS is delayed by 24 - 48 hours.

Here's a sample header from one of the emails.

```
Received: by 10.31.210.130 with SMTP id j124csp1726057vkg;
Tue, 10 Nov 2015 05:39:40 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.107.137.222 with SMTP id t91mr4278192ioi.172.1447162780414;
Tue, 10 Nov 2015 05:39:40 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <noreply@absorbstaging.com>
Received: from app30.absorbstaging.com (ec2-54-223-195-213.cn-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com.cn. [54.223.195.213])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g79si4766429ioj.81.2015.11.10.05.39.37
        for <xxx@xxx.xxx>;
        Tue, 10 Nov 2015 05:39:40 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 54.223.195.213 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of noreply@absorbstaging.com) client-ip=54.223.195.213;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 54.223.195.213 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of noreply@absorbstaging.com) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@absorbstaging.com
Received: from APP30 ([172.31.17.100]) by app30.absorbstaging.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(8.0.9200.16384);
     Mon, 9 Nov 2015 07:36:40 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "GVE Online" <noreply@absorbstaging.com>
To: xxxx@qq.com
Cc: xxxx@qq.com
Date: 9 Nov 2015 07:36:40 +0000
Subject: =?utf-8?B?WW91IGhhdmUgYmVlbiBlbnJvbGxlZCBpbiBCb29rZWQgKEdy?=
 =?utf-8?B?YWRlIDIpIENvdXJ0bmV5IEx1Y2tldHQgVGh1cnNkYXkgMTgwMC0xODMw?=
 =?utf-8?B?IEZhbGwvV2ludGVyIDIwMTUg5aSW5pWZIENvdXJ0bmV5IOWRqOWbmyAx?=
 =?utf-8?B?ODowMC0xODozMCDnp4vlhqzlrabmnJ8gMjAxNSDkvaDlt7Lms6jlhozm?=
 =?utf-8?B?iJDlip8gQm9va2VkIChHcmFkZSAyKSBDb3VydG5leSBMdWNrZXR0IFRo?=
 =?utf-8?B?dXJzZGF5IDE4MDAtMTgzMCBGYWxsL1dpbnRlciAyMDE1IOWkluaVmSBD?=
 =?utf-8?B?b3VydG5leSDlkajlm5sgMTg6MDAtMTg6MzAg56eL5Yas5a2m5pyfIDIw?=
 =?utf-8?B?MTU=?=
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Return-Path: noreply@absorbstaging.com
Message-ID: <APP30lNY30kkZIhTrBo0000269a@app30.absorbstaging.com>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: **09 Nov 2015 07:36:40.0666** (UTC) FILETIME=[5FAD53A0:01D11AC1]
```

As we all know, google services are not allowed in China. Could it be that the SPF is delaying our email?

I'm just a systems admin trying to figure out why our email is delayed, so this is my poking around.

But I could be totally off.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `app30.absorbstaging.com` is your SMTP and in the example email you sending to some gmail.com address.
It depends on how much you send and how long ago you began to send from app30.absorbstaging.com to gmail addresses. If not so much before and not so long ago then your IP address is not warmed up enough and it's not strange if after some amount of emails sent to gmail.com addresses during a day (it can be just like 1000 mails in the begining) gmail stops receiving more and your smtp retrying sending them so your recipient get message finally delayed. Because what I can read you SMTP app30.absorbstaging.com got message on `Mon, 9 Nov 2015 07:36:40 +0000` and mx.google.com received it only on `Tue, 10 Nov 2015 05:39:40 -0800 (PST)` so as I understand it was you app30 smtp that was retrying to send it to mx.google.com all that time because mx.google.com didn't want to accept it.
So the one thing is to continue warming up your IP 54.223.195.213 sending good emails to gmail so gmail can eventually learn your IP as a legitimate bulk email sender and increase dayly acceptable mail volume from this your IP.
I see also that your sender domain absorbstaging.com doesn't have any SPF record that designates smtp (app30.absorbstaging.com) to send emails for sender from absorbstaging.com domain. You definitely need to fix such SPF. It could look like this `v=spf1 a:app30.absorbstaging.com ~all`

Comment: Hi Roman, 
Thank you for a very detailed answer. We will have to test this out with non-gmail emails. 

We have a gmail account setup as CC for outgoing system emails, which is how we monitor the activity. A lot of our clients have reported long email delays. 

So 54.223.195.213 - that's our server in China, has been up since August. How much longer would it need to warm up. 

So perhaps this is only a delay going out from China to gmail services. But I will run some tests on other accounts and see what happens. 

Thank you again.

Comment: very good Alexei. I would recommend not using CC even for monitoring purposes just because it affects deliverability. Try create it's separate email copy  as a normal mail with ordinary reciever.

Comment: Hey Roman, 

I got a response from our systems engineer. He said the following:
Adding an SPF record will not improve or speed up email delivery times . We are noticing many OutboundConnection attempts take 30-120 seconds per SMTP command (HELO, MAIL FOM, RCPT TO, DATA, etc) - and some messages timeout completely when attempting to initially contact the external SMTP Server. The attempts/results we are observing are in alignment with the known blocking and/or throttling of Google services in the mainland of China.